# Cannot find name 'HTMLAttributes'.(2304) in typescript playground

Tags: typescript, typescript-playground

Code:

```
type HTMLDivElementAttibuteKeys = keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
```

Got error:

> Cannot find name 'HTMLAttributes'.(2304)

> Exported type alias 'HTMLDivElementAttibuteKeys' has or is using private name 'HTMLAttributes'.(4081)

I think I need to add the `dom` lib to `tsconfig.json` so that the TSC will recognize the `HTMLAttributes` type. But I can't find where to add it in the typescript playground.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgKgWQDIBECWA3AogGwgWwgDtgBBYYNAIwFdgIBpCEAZygF4oBrZgewDNYiJOWAAnanQgsAPPGTpseQiQB8QA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKBgE8wk4AJAFQFkAZAEWADcBRADZIQSAHYwAgjBjAARgFcYSANJIaAZzgBeOAGs1ETImIwAdCw5SYUOYqTqAPBa69BwsTAB8QA)

Set the module to CommonJS in TSConfig and add React.

Comment: Add `react` module to **plugins** => **Custom npm Modules** section works.